# logging mysql statements executed by jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I tried to log mysql statements , executed by jdbc , hoping to see strings containing *declare some cursor* or *fetch some cursor*. But there was not.
Are there any ways to see them?
PS i set variables in mysql as following:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output="FILE"
SET GLOBAL general_log_file="Path/File"
SET GLOBAL general_log='ON'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Add 'logger' and 'profileSQL' to the jdbc url:

```
&logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger&profileSQL=true
```

Then you will get the SQL statement below:

```
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - FETCH created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 1 connection: 19130945 statement: 999 resultset: 0
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - QUERY created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 1 connection: 19130945 statement: 999 resultset: 0 message: SET sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - FETCH created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 1 connection: 19130945 statement: 999 resultset: 0
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - QUERY created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 2 connection: 19130945 statement: 13 resultset: 17 message: select 1
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - FETCH created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 0 connection: 19130945 statement: 13 resultset: 17
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - QUERY created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 1 connection: 19130945 statement: 15 resultset: 18 message: select @@session.tx_read_only
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - FETCH created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 0 connection: 19130945 statement: 15 resultset: 18
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - QUERY created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 2 connection: 19130945 statement: 14 resultset: 0 message: update sequence set seq=seq+incr where name='demo' and seq=4602
2016-01-14 10:09:43  INFO MySQL - FETCH created: Thu Jan 14 10:09:43 CST 2016 duration: 0 connection: 19130945 statement: 14 resultset: 0
```

The default logger is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger
```

Mysql jdbc property list: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html